# load html form in onclick page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Am using onclick method to select form type.  I have many form types- [here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147276/onclick-method-error/26147329#26147329)

- When I click one onclick sub menu will open and when I select form type the selected form should open bellow the menu
- How do I load a form when I select option in sub menu
- I need to load HTML form in same page but the HTML code will be store in separate HTML file

form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>1st indian site</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../../images/ico/fav.ico" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="formoid_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-blue.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../../css/proper align.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        a{text-decoration:none;}a:hover{}
    </style>
</head><!--/head-->
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
    <header id="header" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php?hfgjiii4wg4fgww86g4gg41"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li  class="active"><a href="#pricing"> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;Post</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!--/#header-->
    <br>        <br><br><br><br><br>
                      <script type="text/javascript" src="formoid_files/formoid1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formoid-solid-blue" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#34495E;max-width:940px;min-width:150px" method="post" action="post forward.php"><div class="title"><h2>Post Free Ad</h2></div>
                    <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Type Of Ad<span class="required"></span></label><div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="type" value="I Want To Sell" required="required"/><span>I Want To Sell</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span><div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="type" value="I Want To Buy" required="required"/><span>I Want To Buy</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
                                                </div><br>
                    <div class="element-input" title="title"><label class="title"><span class="required">Title For Your Ad</span></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="text" name="title" required="required" placeholder="Title For Your Ad"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-file"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><label class="medium" ><div class="button">Choose File</div><input type="file" class="file_input" name="ufile" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" /><div class="file_text">No file selected</div><span class="icon-place"></span></label></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-file"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><label class="medium" ><div class="button">Choose File</div><input type="file" class="file_input" name="ufile1" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" /><div class="file_text">No file selected</div><span class="icon-place"></span></label></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-file"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><label class="medium" ><div class="button">Choose File</div><input type="file" class="file_input" name="ufile2" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" /><div class="file_text">No file selected</div><span class="icon-place"></span></label></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-file"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><label class="medium" ><div class="button">Choose File</div><input type="file" class="file_input" name="ufile3" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" /><div class="file_text">No file selected</div><span class="icon-place"></span></label></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-file"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><label class="medium" ><div class="button">Choose File</div><input type="file" class="file_input" name="ufile4" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" /><div class="file_text">No file selected</div><span class="icon-place"></span></label></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-select"><label class="title"><span class="required">Select Your Mobile Brand</span></label><div class="item-cont"><div class="medium"><span><select name="mobilebrand" required="required">
                                        <option value="">..</option>
                                        <option value="ASUS">ASUS</option>
                                        <option value="Vertu">Vertu</option>
                                        <option value="Vodafone">Vodafone</option>
                                        <option value="LG">LG</option>
                                        <option value="O2">O2</option>
                                        <option value="HTC">HTC</option>
                                        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                                        <option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
                                        <option value="FLY">FLY</option>
                                        <option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
                                        <option value="Zen">Zen</option>
                                        <option value="Palm">Palm</option>
                                        <option value="Viva">Viva</option>
                                        <option value="Intex">Intex</option>
                                        <option value="Karbonn">Karbonn</option>
                                        <option value="Lava">Lava</option>
                                        <option value="Tata Indicom">Tata Indicom</option>
                                        <option value="Rocker">Rocker</option>
                                        <option value="Lemon">Lemon</option>
                                        <option value="Wynncom">Wynncom</option>
                                        <option value="Virgin Mobile">Virgin Mobile</option>
                                        <option value="G-Five">G-Five</option>
                                        <option value="Gee Pee">Gee Pee</option>
                                        <option value="INQ">INQ</option>
                                        <option value="Iball">Iball</option>
                                        <option value="AirFone">AirFone</option>
                                        <option value="Acer">Acer</option>
                                        <option value="Byond">Byond</option>
                                        <option value="Beetel">Beetel</option>
                                        <option value="Sagem">Sagem</option>
                                        <option value="Toshiba">Toshiba</option>
                                        <option value="BenQ">BenQ</option>
                                        <option value="Pantech">Pantech</option>
                                        <option value="Videocon">Videocon</option>
                                        <option value="Spice">Spice</option>
                                        <option value="ZTE">ZTE</option>
                                        <option value="BlackBerry">BlackBerry</option>
                                        <option value="Maxx">Maxx</option>
                                        <option value="Apple iPhone">Apple iPhone</option>
                                        <option value="Micromax">Micromax</option>
                                        <option value="Sony Ericsson">Sony Ericsson</option>
                                        <option value="HP">HP</option>
                                        <option value="Motorola">Motorola</option>
                                        <option value="Dell">Dell</option>
                                        <option value="I-Mate">I-Mate</option>
                                        <option value="Other">Other</option></select><i></i><span class="icon-place"></span></span></div></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-input"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="text" name="mobilemodel" required="required" placeholder="Select Your Model"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
                    <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Condition<span class="required">*</span></label>        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="mobilecond" value="New" required="required"/><span>New</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
                        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="mobilecond" value="Used" required="required"/><span>Used</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="element-input"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="small" type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-input"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Your Location(enter Your Town or Village Name)"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-textarea"><label class="title"><span class="required"></span></label><div class="item-cont"><textarea class="small" name="description" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Description About Your Mobile"></textarea><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div><br>
                    <hr><center><h3>Seller Information</h3></center>
                    <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">You Are <span class="required"></span></label>      <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="youare" value="Dealer" required="required"/><span>Dealer</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
                        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="youare" value="Individual" required="required"/><span>Individual</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element-name"><label class="title"></label><span class="nameFirst"><input placeholder="Name" type="text" size="8" name="name" /><span class="icon-place"></span></span></div><br>
                    <div class="element-email"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="email" name="email" value="" required="required" placeholder="Email"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div><br>
                    <div class="element-phone"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="tel" pattern="[+]?[\.\s\-\(\)\*\#0-9]{3,}" maxlength="24" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div><br>
                    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div></form><script type="text/javascript" src="formoid_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-blue.js"></script>

</body>
```

yhis the form am using how do i open this form.php in same page when i click in sub menu

Comment: If all you are doing is loading an html form, `$('#targetElement').load('formPage.html')` would probably do it inside of the onclick. You would obviously need to change the target and html page based on what was clicked.

Comment: Rather than loading something static like a form, consider building all the forms into your page and hiding them.  You then reveal the form or forms that you require.  Reading static content from another file isn't worth it unless you are going to reuse it a component, or unless it's a lot to download.  Otherwise your users will see better performance from the hide/reveal approach.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn where to ad that code

Comment: "...inside of the onclick." -me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are doing is loading an html form, `$('#targetElement').load('formPage.html')` would probably do it inside of the onclick.