# Open html form below home page Onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

I am using on click method [onclick example am using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147276/onclick-method-error/26151639#26151639)

I am using two step Onclick method when I click 2nd Onclick a HTML form should open in same page how do I do that

- since I am using many sub categories Like ,mobile, computer, etc,...
- so I have many sub form
- when user click sub form the linked form should open in same page [here is the working example Onclick method](http://sanojtest.comoj.com/final%20project%20test/cki586fg6e8d56w984f5/ahmedbdkfdyemopfg23tg85/)
  what I need is how to open html form file below

Comment: By two-step onclick method, do you mean a double-click? As in, two clicks in rapid succession? Or do you mean that when you click it the first time, it does something else, and then when you click it a second time, it shows your form?

Comment: @Travesty3 no at first click it will open another menu and in 2nd menu it should open form bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ugjj2yo/2/
In short: bind click events on each 1:st menu item, and then on 2:nd menu item.
Each click handler should close "all other" of the same kind when you click it, then open whatever you clicked (if you want more forms to be displayed at the same time, remove all rows that call

```
.hide();
```

The css supplied in the fiddle is just temporary, change it to whatever, the only thing you can't change is the

```
display:none;
```

thats there already. (You could also hide them on page load with jquery ofc..)