# open HTML form in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using link to open html form

My question is: How do I make an html form open below.

CODE

```
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a href="mobile.html">Mobile&nbsp;Phones</a>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a href="tablet.html">Tablets</a></p>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a href="accessories.html">Mobile&nbsp;Accessories</a></p>
```

when I click link on the link the file should open in same page.

mobile.php

```
 *mobile form field*
```

tablet.php

```
 *tablet form field*
```

accessories.php

```
 *accessories form field*
```

Comment: You should google for: ajax.

Comment: Frames or Ajax. There are many tutorials. Writing another would be too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: why is it so important to keep it all on the 1 page, you could move off the page and make the parser and the form the 1 page keeping your project scalable and easy for other developers to edit in the future.

Comment: this the page am using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147276/onclick-method-error/26147329?noredirect=1#comment40987686_26147329

Comment: this method is fast in my project so i need this method or can u mention this method name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged jquery, you could just `.load()` method in this case:

```
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="mobile.html">Mobile&nbsp;Phones</a>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="tablet.html">Tablets</a></p>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="accessories.html">Mobile&nbsp;Accessories</a></p>

<div class="page"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.reveal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.page').load(link);
    });

});
</script>
```

Or just a simple iframe also:

```
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="mobile.html" target="page">Mobile&nbsp;Phones</a>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="tablet.html" target="page">Tablets</a></p>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="accessories.html" target="page">Mobile&nbsp;Accessories</a></p>

<iframe src="" name="page" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I don't understand why you want to do this, but if you wanted to hide the links other than the one you clicked, just add this inside onclick callback after `.load()`:

```
$('.reveal').hide();
$(this).show();
```

Comment: i need to open linked page in same page, the linked page is form

Comment: @sanojlawrence yes, `.load()` does that, it just loads that particular html. did you try it?

Comment: working on just a min

Comment: thanks that works fine but how do i disappear the other option when i click mobile i need to disappear the other two option

Comment: @sanojlawrence could you elaborate on that? if i click `mobile`, the `tablet, accesories` will be hidden? why do you want to do that?

Comment: yes when i click mobile i need to disappear the other two option because it looks clean because i have 15 menu like that (mobile,tablet,etc) so i need to disappear other option